# redmine + outlook.com (ex hotmail) for custom domain actionmailer config

Tags: actionmailer, redmine, hotmail, outlook.com

We use outlook.com (ex hotmail) as mail for our organisation.
I'm trying to make redmine to send notifications with our outlook.com account.
Redmine 2.3.1 on Debian 7 with ruby from distribution.
I've found that since 2.3 option openssl_verify_mode doesn't matter, and merged with enable_starttls_auto (at least in my conf it seems like has no effect), but i'm not sure.
I've tried some versions of settings in config/configuration.yml but I've failed.

```
default:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      enable_starttls_auto:     true
      address:                  "smtp.live.com"
      port:                     587
      domain:                   "customdomain.com"
      authentication:           :plain
      user_name:                email@customdomain.com
      password:                 passwd
```

gets

```
An error occurred while sending mail (SSL_read:: wrong version number)
```

and alternative version

```
default:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      enable_starttls_auto:     false
      address:                  "smtp.live.com"
      port:                     587
      domain:                   "customdomain.com"
      authentication:           :plain
      user_name:                email@customdomain.com
      password:                 passwd
```

gets

```
An error occurred while sending mail (530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first )
```

If anybody faced with such problem and have solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is [a bug in the Mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/659), as [user3261218 describes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21502596/596068). It affects other gems dependent on Mail, [such as Pony](https://github.com/adamwiggins/pony/issues/3).

The fix is to explicitly specify the SSL version used. Until the Mail gem is updated, you can apply [the patch](https://github.com/AlexRevin/mail/commit/a12f77d49c3957bddce3b76cf67587f76fa1acc9#diff-e3729936fa9291d1a4ff988ac78acc12) manually by editing `lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb` in the Mail gem source.

For Mail gem version 2.5.4, this means adding the following line after line number 138

```ruby
context.ssl_version = :SSLv3
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue and solution described in Mail-gem issue tracker

https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/659

The fix itself is in the following commit:

https://github.com/AlexRevin/mail/commit/a12f77d49c3957bddce3b76cf67587f76fa1acc9

Comment: Link-only answers are not really answers (even though they may provide a solution), since they depend on external content that could be dead. Is there a way to expand this to be self-contained?